# Perl string replace: Match, but not replace, part of regex

Tags: regex, string, perl

Say I have a string in Perl I am trying to match and replace with stuff:

```
$string =~ s/[^a-zA-Z]$find[^a-zA-Z]/$replace/g;
```

So as shown, I want to replace everything that is surrounded on both sides by nonletter characters.  However, when I replace the string, I do NOT want to also replace these characters: they are just necessary for correct matching.  How can I tell the Perl regex to avoid replacing the things surrounding `$find`?

Comment: Do you want to locate text that is sandwiched between non-alphabetic characters? Or do you want to match a pattern but excluding alphabetic characters? The two tests are not the same at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: My intent was to do the first of the two.  Both sln's and hjpotter92's answers accomplish this, not sure about ergonaut's.

Comment: Also have a look at [\b](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Assertions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use perl [lookaround assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions).

```
s/(?<=[^a-zA-Z])$find(?=[^a-zA-Z])/$replace/g
```

Answer (score 4):

Store them as a matched group, and reference them in the replacement string:

```
$string =~ s/([^a-z])$find([^A-Z])/\1$replace\2/gi;
```

Comment: Although using `\1` and `\2` on the RHS of a substitution works, [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-\1-Instead-of-%241) calls it "a dirty habit to get into." You should use `$1` and `$2` instead.